# Creating n number of variable sized buttons in a container

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml

I need to create UI as following (kind of a tag cloud control)

- n number of buttons (Count will be determined during runtime)
- Each button will have different width based on its content
- Max 3 buttons in a row

[image: Buttons with different widths]

I have tried following things

- VariableSizedWrapGrid as ItemsPanel of GridView (It requires RowSpan
  and ColumnSpan to be specified which is not feasible as width is
  determined during runtime)
- StackPanel with Horizontal orientation (All the buttons were arranged in one line)

Any thoughts?

Comment: How about using stackpanel with Vertical orientation and within it stackpanel with Horizontal orientation containing max of 3 buttons?

Comment: @Pratyay,  well, that can be done but if I add 3 buttons in a every horizontal stackpanel, it may result in too long rows if all 3 buttons have longer content. Of course, horizontal scrollbar can be added but it would be good to avoid the horizontal scroll bar in my case, Any other better solution?

Comment: Well the easy way out of the long rows issue would be defining MaxWidth for the buttons to be 1/3 of the stack width(and considering the margin between the buttons that stackpanel adds by default)..but that would crop out content (or text) within the button..also considering you are building a UWP application it should be able to scale to any screen resolution seamlessly you should switch to VariableSizedWrapGrid or check the screen size on GridSizeChanged event and fill the contents accordingly(which will have severe performance issues if not handled correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2015/02/20/Creating-a-WrapPanel-for-your-Windows-Runtime-apps.aspx) is a great blogpost on how to create a WrapPanel based on your requirements.

I have created a `TagsPanel` based off of this blog to use in one of my app. Key is to loop through to items and get the actual size and set it based on available width of the panel. See below.

```cs
public class TagsPanel : Panel
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        // Just take up all of the width
        Size finalSize = new Size { Width = availableSize.Width };
        double x = 0;
        double rowHeight = 0d;
        foreach (var child in Children)
        {
            // Tell the child control to determine the size needed
            child.Measure(availableSize);

            x += child.DesiredSize.Width;
            if (x > availableSize.Width)
            {
                // this item will start the next row
                x = child.DesiredSize.Width;

                // adjust the height of the panel
                finalSize.Height += rowHeight;
                rowHeight = child.DesiredSize.Height;
            }
            else
            {
                // Get the tallest item
                rowHeight = Math.Max(child.DesiredSize.Height, rowHeight);
            }
        }

        // Add the final height
        finalSize.Height += rowHeight;
        return finalSize;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        Rect finalRect = new Rect(0, 0, finalSize.Width, finalSize.Height);

        double rowHeight = 0;
        foreach (var child in Children)
        {
            if ((child.DesiredSize.Width + finalRect.X) > finalSize.Width)
            {
                // next row!
                finalRect.X = 0;
                finalRect.Y += rowHeight;
                rowHeight = 0;
            }
            // Place the item
            child.Arrange(new Rect(finalRect.X, finalRect.Y, child.DesiredSize.Width, child.DesiredSize.Height));

            // adjust the location for the next items
            finalRect.X += child.DesiredSize.Width;
            rowHeight = Math.Max(child.DesiredSize.Height, rowHeight);
        }
        return finalSize;
    }
}
```

and use it in a `GridView` like below.

```xml
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding tags}" >
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding ''}" Margin="5"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <local:TagsPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted!

Comment: This code will drop error when you place TagsPanel inside the grid with ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"

Answer (score 2):

Basically, VariableSizedWrapGrid treat all its childs with equal size. You can use ColumnSpan and RowSpan to extend the area of child.

Another way is to create a [WrapPanel](https://comentsys.wordpress.com/2015/05/27/windows-10-universal-windows-platform-wrap-control/) user control and then use in place of VariableSizedWrapGrid. This will shape output as you described.

Comment: UWP doesn't have WrapPanel while the same is available in WPF. You'll need to create WrapPanel user control and use in place of VariableSizedWrapGrid in xaml.